# jQuery DataTables: selecting a row shows the hidden child details twice

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

We are using datatables in our application. The columns information cannot be fit in to the total width of datatable, so some of the columns are hidden automatically. Once we click on a row in the datatable, it displays the hidden columns and values. But the issue is it was displayed twice.

[Datatable issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3piCs.png)

Comment: "My car is broken, how can I fix it?" That's not enough info. We would need some code, something to work with...

Comment: Maybe this is a better place to ask your question: http://www.datatables.net/forums/
Do keep us posted on the solution though...

Comment: Ah, you already did I guess: http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/26263/selecting-a-row-shows-the-hidden-child-details-twice

Comment: Yes, I already posted it in the datatables forums.

Comment: I just used the default bootstrap js file which has the datatables js functions. I didn't modify/add any extra code either.